# How to set visibility in Angular from Directive on Mouse events

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I am trying to handle visibility of links on mouse events,
When user mouseover on link, link should be visible, and on mouseout link should be hidden.
For some reason, I am able to add hidden style to an element, but once an element is hidden, I am not able to change it to visible on mouseover.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <caption style="caption-side: top; text-align: center;">Food Items</caption>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor='let food of foods'>
            <td>
                <a hideShowElement [routerLink]="" class="link-danger" (click)='deleteFoodItem(food.id)'>DELETE</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My directive,

```
import { Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostBinding, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[hideShowElement]'
})
export class HideShowDirective {

    @HostBinding('style.visibility') visibility: string;

  constructor(private elementr: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
    
   }

    @HostListener('mouseover') 
    onMouseOver() {
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.elementr.nativeElement, 'visibility', 'visible');
    }
 
    @HostListener('mouseleave') 
    onMouseLeave() {
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.elementr.nativeElement, 'visibility', 'hidden');
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to do a trick with color and disabled attribute. I want to hide it and show it.

Answer (score 1):

There is one more work around for the given problem, you can use matTooltip to show the link when the user hover on that particular HTML element. Then attach (click) method to the element for redirecting to that particular URL.

I hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It is not **visibility**. Please try with **display** property. Display property value was **display:none** and **display:block**

Comment: Same behavior, I am able to apply NONE on mouseleave event for the first time, but when I do mouseover, style is not applying, because element is removed by this time.

Comment: Okay I got your actual problem

Comment: You can set the text color same as your background color I think it's working for you

Comment: So the behavior is look like hidden and shown on mouse hover and mouse leave.

Comment: also apply disable property with your hidden functionality so user will not able to click on them